# how to count the clicking of notification builder

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I send notification to my users by NotificationCompat.Builder .i have a **separate class** for notification builder **in a library that i created and imported to my project** . 
now I want to **count the number of users that click on notification** but i  don't know how its work . here is my code :

```
public class notify{
public static void notifyMsg(Context context, String txt, String channelId, String title, long id)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId);
    b.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setTicker("Hearty365")
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setContentText(txt)
            .setChannelId(channelId)
            .setVibrate(new long[]

                    {
                            100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400
                    })
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentInfo("Info");

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, b.build());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The contentIntent you are setting here is not taegetting to any specific activity which opens when you click on the notification. The intent needs to be set with activity class via its setClass or constructor method.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("src","notify")
    intent.setClass(MyActivity.class);
```

Within your activity, check if your activity is launched with extra data as above :

```
if(getIntent().getString("src")!=null 
    && "notify".equals(getIntent().getString("src"))){
        // Implementation of counting stuff
}
```